# How can I call a soap web service using apache-camel

Tags: wsdl, apache-camel, soap-client

I have a soap web service running of some server .

```xml
<wsdl:operation name="lookup">
<wsdl:input message="tns:LookupRequest" name="LookupRequest"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:LookupResponse" name="LookupResponse"> 
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

It has lookup as a web service and this web service takes LookupRequest 
object as an input.

So my question is how can I call this lookup web service using apache camel 
and how can i give input to this web service i.e: lookup object.

And also how can i figure our wheather its a jax-ws because i only have the 
wsdl file and I want to create client for that web service using apache- 
camel.

LookupRequest Class looks like this:-

```
public class LookupRequest {

        @XmlElement(name = "EntityReference")
        protected List<EntityReference> references;
        @XmlElement(name = "AttachmentReference")
        protected List<AttachmentLookupReference> attachmentReferences;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "countryCode")
        protected String countryCode;
        @XmlAttribute(name = "languageCode")
        protected String languageCode;
}
```

Do i need to create lookupRequest object and send it to the server or I can send String as well?

Comment: You can use the Camel CXF component (https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-cxf/src/main/docs/cxf-component.adoc) to talk to the webservice. CXF can generate classes from WSDL. Google for "camel cxf consume webservice example", you surely find an example. Good luck

Comment: On top of what @burki said, here is a [simple example](https://cleverbuilder.com/articles/camel-soap-service/). You will have to construct a bean to make that request. Strings won't quite cut AFAIK.

Comment: In apache cxf documentation it was written that the cxf: component provides integration with Apache CXF for connecting to JAX-WS services hosted in CXF .How to figure out wheather the soap web service is hosted in cxf as of now i only have the wsdl file.

Comment: CXF (as well as Camel-CXF) can connect to any webservice based on the WSDL. It is not limited to CXF implementations on the "other side"

Answer (score 1):

First you need to generate the client from WSDL with the help of CXF [wsdl2java](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html). Then you can leverage the camel-cxf component to send the request to service that you want to invoke server, here is [an example](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-cxf-proxy) that you may take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send xml request:

First set the two headers
.setheader("operationNamespace",the namespace that tns is alias for)
.setheader("operationName","lookup")

and then use the cfx component
"cxf:{{url}}?wsdlURL=someWsdlInclasspath.wsdl&dataFormat=payload"

then you can send the request as xml (in body)